# Issue overloading operator << in C++

Tags: c++

```
Compiler: MSVC
```

So I am trying to implement my own number system that can store infinite numbers in C++. What I did was overload `operator<<` for my custom class `BigInt` as such:

```
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, BigInt& bint)
{
    os << bint.num; // num is a std::string
    return os;
}
```

Now I implemented addition for my custom numbers:

```
inline BigInt& operator+(BigInt& bint1, BigInt& bint2)
{
    BigInt sum;

    // addition code...

    return sum;
}
```

Now when I try to print a `BigInt` like this:

```
BigInt bint1("123");
std::cout << bint1;
```

..it works. But nothing prints out when I do this:

```
BigInt bint1("123"), bint2("456");
std::cout << bint1 + bint2;
```

I suspect some sort of UB here. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're correct that it's UB. But it's not in the `operator<<` function, it's in the `operator+` function where you return a reference to a local variable. You should return by value instead.

Comment: Does your C++ textbook have an explanation why returning a reference to an object that's declared local in a function, being returned from, is always wrong, and why?

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings.  Your compiler should have warned you about this particular bug in your code.